# need count value is 0 means the output is displayed

Tags: java, mysql, loops, conditional-statements

i have try to develop one java app.here am getting information from mysql database.
my code is:

```
public class RetailerWs {
  public int data(){
    int count=0;
    try {
      Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
      Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/pro","root","");
      PreparedStatement statement =  con.prepareStatement("select * from orders where status='Q' AND MONTH(date) = MONTH(CURDATE()) AND YEAR(date) = YEAR(CURDATE())");
      ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();
      while(result.next()) {
        // Do something with the row returned.
        count++; //if the first col is a count.
      }
    }
    catch(Exception exc){
      System.out.println(exc.getMessage());
    }
    return count;
  }
}
```

the other class is :

```
 public class Demo {
 public static void main(String[] args){
    RetailerWs obj = new RetailerWs();
    System.out.println(obj.data());
 }

}
```

Here i have to check the query and display count value is successfully.but my doubt is the query matched item is zero means the output is displayed blankly.but i wish to need it is display 0.not display blank screen..so please help me how is to do.

Comment: your class name is RetailerWs  and you are creating object of MonthC  class..why??

Comment: And use `SELECT COUNT(*)...` instead of `SELECT * ...`.

Comment: class `RetailerWS` and `MonthC` are supposed to be the same class?

Comment: It should print some integer value , at least a zero. Did you run the program ? with above mentioned mistakes, I doubt you did. Please verify.

Comment: @Axel did you that see he is iterating over the resultset ? So he didn't user COUNT function here.

Comment: if i run the Demo class means it is check database for above query.no query is matched.so the output is displayed blankly.but no one is matched for above query means i wish to display output is 0.how is to do

Comment: @sakthisundar but with COUNT(*) iteration is not necessary anymore and the result is the same.

Comment: @jelies Yeah. I understand that. But that is how he has coded. I was only trying to make that point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the object of class RetailerWs.

```
RetailerWs  obj =new RetailerWs ();
System.out.println(obj.data());
```

Comment: if i run the Demo class means it is check database for above query.no query is matched.so the output is displayed blankly.but i wish to know the output is display 0.how is to do

Answer (score 0):

The statement

```
System.out.println(new RetailerWs().data());
```

wil **always, unconditionally** print an integer value, even if that value is 0. Unless an exception prevents it from executing, that is.